# Automatically adjusting UITableView height to display only the UITableViewCell(s) present

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

It seems that `UITableView` does not auto-calculate the exact height needed to cover all the visible cells, instead, it substitutes any extra area with empty rows.

I'd like to calculate the exact height needed to cover only the visible cells, as to rid my `UITableView` of those ugly empty rows. I am quite aware that this can be done manually using the Interface Builder, however there must be a more efficient and dynamic approach to this problem.

Comment: The separator itself shouldn't add any height to the cell…  Are you using a grouped or plain UITableView?  Is there a header?  If it's a plain tableview with no header, the math you described in your last paragraph should be right.

Comment: It's a plain UITableView. It doesn't have a header though.

Comment: Then maybe you're calculating the average height incorrectly…  Are you calculating it as a float?

Comment: Actually, go with Mike's answer!  No calculation needed :)

Comment: You know what? I actually ended up having that same issue last night…where the last half of my last cell was hidden for some reason.  I fixed the issue by turning off auto-layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the table view's content size to determine how much space the table wants.

```
CGFloat height = myTableView.contentSize.height;
```

This `height` will automatically consider headers, footers, and the size and number of cells, and pretty much anything else.  And it's all dynamic, so if you decide to go to a 7 row table in the future, it will still work without a problem and without needing to change that piece of code.  The only time you would need to change it is if you decided at some point that you no longer want to show the whole table anymore.

And a quick tip - you'll probably want to also set `[myTableView setScrollEnabled:NO]`.  Disabling scrolling will prevent the table from "bouncing" if the user does try to scroll it - I just think that bouncing looks really silly if all the content of the table is being shown at once.

You can then use this `height` to either

- adjust the constraints on your table view (if you are using Autolayout)
- adjust the `frame` of your table view (if you use the old springs-and-struts approach)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to get set cellHeight member variable and use it where ever required.

```
_cellHeight = floorf((CGRectGetHeight(self.tableView.bounds))/5);
```

This should give you height of each row and it will handle all cases.
The above code has to be used in following methods.

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews;
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;
```

I hope this helps.